# How to assign a keyboard shortcut to a run configuration in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea

It seems you can assign a keyboard shortcut to almost everything else, but I can't see an option to do this for run/debug configurations?

The "run configurations" are listed in the drop-down on the IntelliJ toolbar. I'd like to setup a run configuration that can perform two maven tasks sequentially (jetty:stop and then jetty:run if you are interested), and assign a keyboard shortcut to this action.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! JetBrains has [implemented this feature](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/10/invoking-rundebug-actions-in-intellij-idea-9/) in IntelliJ IDEA v9.

Answer (score 1):

in Idea 8 anyway, you can specify a shortcut to any file menu item- even Maven goals.  Try settings- Keymap and look for the Maven goals.   You will still probably need two keys.  One for each action.

Comment: Yeah it seems you can shortcut file menu items, maven goals - pretty much everything EXCEPT run/debug configurations. Weird. So that means there is no way to run two maven targets sequentially with one keyboard shortcut.